# Can't get GIF animated

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I can't get an animated GIF animated within a CLabel. I also tried Label.

```
final CLabel lblSpinner = new CLabel(this, SWT.NONE);
lblSpinner.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(Installation_4.class, "/resources/spinner_anim_16.gif"));
```

What's wrong? Only the first GIF is displayed. In RCP I have to animate programatically but in RAP this must be a job for the browser I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works with RAP, with both `Label` and `CLabel`:

```
public class AnimatedGifSnippet implements IEntryPoint {

  public int createUI() {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell( display );
    shell.setLayout( new GridLayout() );

    Image image = createImage( display, "resources/loading.gif" );
    Label label = new Label( shell, SWT.NONE );
    label.setImage( image );

    shell.layout();
    shell.open();
    return 0;
  }

  private Image createImage( Display display, String resourceName ) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream( resourceName );
    if( inputStream == null ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Resource not found: " + resourceName );
    }
    try {
      return new Image( display, inputStream );
    } finally {
      try {
        inputStream.close();
      } catch( IOException exception ) {
        // TODO handle exception
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work with your image, then the problem is in the image image itself. Otherwise, you must be doing something wrong in your `SWTResourceManager.getImage()` method. Please note that if you construct an `Image` from `ImageData`, these will only contain a single frame of the animated gif.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. In the SWTResourceManager the Image was created from ImageData as you mentioned.